# How does a incoming call show my location?

Tags: call-screening, caller-id

I got a spam call on my mobile recently and while the phone was ringing, on the screen I can see my location displayed along with incoming person's name.
Why my phone was showing my own location for this particular call?
Does it mean that my phone is compromised or something?

Edit:
Just before the call, I was having a call with a scammer who was trying to trick me to enter my bank details through a phishing site (which I entered some random numbers, but correct phone number)

Answer (score 1):

When many phones receive incoming calls, they display the incoming number as well as an approximate location of the incoming call, usually based on a table lookup for the country code / area code / prefix of the Caller ID of the incoming call.

The Caller ID data is easy to forge, so often scammers set it to match whatever location they are calling (by matching your country code / area code / prefix).  This way, when they call, it looks like a local call, and they believe you are more likely to pick up the phone.  But, in reality, they can be calling from anywhere in the world.

When they set their Caller ID to match the country code / area code / prefix of your phone number, your approximate location will appear on your screen because that is simply the location associated with that Caller ID data.

The best way I have found to circumvent their tactics is to get a phone number with a completely different country code / area code / prefix from where you live or typically travel and different from any of your close contacts.  That way, when an incoming call uses Caller ID data that is similar to yours, you quickly know it is most likely a scammer.

Answer (score 0):

Most cell phone towers know and publish their exact location. If your phone is now in an area with multiple cell phone towers in reception range it is a simple mathematical task to triangulate your position based on the phone tower locations and the signal strength to each cell tower.

The more towers there are in reception range and the smaller the signal covering area of each cell phone tower is, the better the calculated location.

As modern 4G and 5G cells in city areas are getting smaller and smaller the calculated location can be very accurate nowadays.